# Long waiting time reading file in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I'm currenly running a codeigniter website and i'm trying to read and process a simple .csv file hosted in another URL.

I have the code working good, but I experienced long waiting times no mather the size of the file.

```
        $target_file = "https://website.com/uploads/import_orders.txt";
        $extension = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $allowed_ext = array("csv", "txt");
        if (in_array($extension, $allowed_ext)) {

            $handle     = fopen($target_file, "r");
            if (empty($handle) === false) {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) {
                    print_r($data);
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }


        }
```

The file is processed and printed correctly. But no mather if there are 2 rows or 500 rows, it always waits at least 5 minutes.

I tested it inserting values in the database and it's curious, all the values are almost inserted in no time except the latest row. When the execution ends it adds the latest row values.

It's like the file is not closed correctly or something and the server keeps waiting.

Any clues about whats happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Other than the long wait time, is the code giving the expected result and with no errors?

Comment: Yes, code is working properly, it's just the long wait what i don't know how to solve.

Comment: What's the OS and PHP version?

Comment: I don't think it's a server issue, but here it goes:

PHP 5.5.9, MySQL 5.5
LINUX
Dell PowerEdge R210

Comment: What is your maximum execution time in php.ini?

Comment: max_execution_time is set as 300. It seems to be something related to this, but I don't understand why the program has to wait until is forced to end by max_execution_time

Comment: It's definitely something with the while. The docs do seem to suggest you're doing it right, but the while loop isn't ending.